# Add radio button list items programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button list whose items I need to add on `Page_Load`

aspx code

```
<asp:radioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
</asp:radioButtonList>
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList radioList = (RadioButtonList)Page.FindControl("radio1");
    radioList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));
}
```

After the control reaches `radioList.Items.Add`

I keep getting the `Object reference not set to instance of an object`
 error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `radio1` inside another asp.net control like a repeater or something like that?

Comment: You can access the radioButtonList from code behind just calling the ID radio1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));

Comment: If its on same page why dont you directly write radio1.Items.Add? If not please edit your question.

Comment: @Claudio Redi: It is embedded inside a series of <div> elements

Comment: Yes, I can access it now using radio1.Items.Add

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need to to do a FindCOntrol. As you used the runat="server" attributes, just get the reference of your RadioList via its name "radio1"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radio1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using

```
RadioButtonList radioList = (RadioButtonList)Page.FindControl("radio1");
radioList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));
```

you are not adding your list on the control on your page, but on an un-instanciated Radiobuttonlist called radioList.

If the page is reachable from the class, use

```
radio1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you must add !ispostback

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        radio1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Apple", "1"));
    }
```

Comment: This part : RadioButtonList radioList = (RadioButtonList)Page.FindControl("radio1"); still won't be working.

Comment: Its really important when using MultiView to prevent items to be added multiple times. Thanks man !

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using the < **asp:** **> tools -
I needed to reuse a radio option which relies on a lot of jQuery integration in the site. (Also wanted to avoid just CSS hiding the content within the html code of the aspx page.)

The radio buttons needed only appear in an 'edit' page depending on security ACU level logic within the codebehind and rendered with currently stored item value data found in the db.
So I used the following:

```
string RadioOnChk1  = (db.fieldChecked == true) ? "checked='checked'" : "";
string RadioOnChk2  = (db.fieldChecked == false) ? "checked='checked'" : "";

if (ACU > 3)
{
// Create radio buttons with pre-checked
  StringBuilder RadioButtns = new StringBuilder(); // Form input values
  {
   RadioButtns.Append("<p><label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radiocomm1\" name=\"custmComm\" value=\"1\"");
   RadioButtns.Append(RateIncChk1 + "/>Included or </label>");
   RadioButtns.Append("<label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radiocomm2\" name=\"custmComm\" value=\"2\"");
   RadioButtns.Append(RateIncChk2 + "/>Excluded</label>");
   RadioButtns.Append("</p>");
  }
  htmlVariable = (RadioButtns.ToString());
}
```

It works.. Is this a wrong way of going about it?